# Sort comma-delimited file by three columns with custom criteria in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting

I have a comma-delimited, text file. I want to sort the file by the 3rd column first, then the 2nd column, then the 1st column.

However, I want the 3rd column to be sorted alphabetically, with the longest value first.

For example, AAA, then AA, then A, then BBB, then BB, then B, then CCC, then CC, and so on.

Input (alpha-sort-test2.txt):

```
JOHN,1,A
MARY,3,AA
FRED,5,BBB
SAM,7,A
JOHN,3,AAA
JOHN,2,AAA
BETTY,2,AAA
JARROD,7,AAA
JOANNE,2,BB
AMANDA,2,DD
AMY,5,B
PETE,7,CC
MATT,4,B
SARAH,3,CCC
GEORGE,3,CC
AMANDA,3,AAA
```

The Perl code that I have so far is as follows:

```
$infile = "alpha-sort-test2.txt";
$outfile = "alpha-sort-test-sorted2.txt";

open (INFILE, "<$infile") or die "Could not open file $infile $!";
open (OUTFILE, ">$outfile");

my @array = sort howtosort <INFILE>;

foreach (@array)
{
   chomp;
   print "$_\n";
   print OUTFILE "$_\n"; 
}

sub howtosort 
{
   my @flds_a = split(/,/, $a);
   my @flds_b = split(/,/, $b);

   $flds_a[2] cmp $flds_b[2]; 
}

close INFILE;
close OUTFILE;
```

Current output (alpha-sort-test-sorted2.txt):

```
JOHN,1,A
SAM,7,A
MARY,3,AA
AMANDA,3,AAA
JOHN,3,AAA
JOHN,2,AAA
BETTY,2,AAA
JARROD,7,AAA
AMY,5,B
MATT,4,B
JOANNE,2,BB
FRED,5,BBB
PETE,7,CC
GEORGE,3,CC
SARAH,3,CCC
AMANDA,2,DD
```

Desired output:

```
BETTY,2,AAA
JOHN,2,AAA
AMANDA,3,AAA
JOHN,3,AAA
JARROD,7,AAA
MARY,3,AA
JOHN,1,A
SAM,7,A
FRED,5,BBB
JOANNE,2,BB
MATT,4,B
AMY,5,B
SARAH,3,CCC
GEORGE,3,CC
PETE,7,CC
AMANDA,2,DD
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a little complication with that criterion for the third field.

Lexicographical comparison goes char by char, so `abc` is lesser-than `ax` but longer strings are greater, with all else equal. So `ab` is lesser-than `b` but `ab` is greater-than `a`.

Thus that requirement for the third field mixes these two things and breaks `cmp` right down the middle. If we were to use `cmp` then `ab` comes before `b` (correct) but `aa` comes after `a` (not wanted). I don't see how to make use of [cmp](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) at all for that requirement.

So here's a very basic implementation of it, for these criteria

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Path::Tiny qw(path);  # convenience

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 file\n";
my @lines = path($file)->lines({ chomp => 1 });

my @sorted =
    map { $_->[0] }
    sort { custom_sort($a, $b) }
    map { [$_, split /,/]  }
    @lines;

say for @sorted;


sub custom_sort {
    my ($aa, $bb) = @_;

    # Last field for both terms, their lengths
    my ($af, $bf) = map { $_->[-1] } $aa, $bb;
    my ($len_a, $len_b) = map { length } $af, $bf;

    # Strip and return first characters and compare them lexicographically
    # Then compare lengths of original strings if needed
    # Keep going until difference is found or one string is depleted
    while (
        (my $ca = substr $af, 0, 1, "")  and
        (my $cb = substr $bf, 0, 1, "")    )
    {
        if ($ca gt $cb) {
            return 1
        }
        elsif ($ca lt $cb) {
            return -1;
        }
        elsif ($len_a < $len_b) {
            return 1
        }
        elsif ($len_a > $len_b) {
            return -1
        }
    }

    # Still here, so third field was the same; use other two criteria
    return
        $aa->[2] <=> $bb->[2]
            ||
        $aa->[1] cmp $bb->[1];
}
```

This prints out the desired list.

Some comments

- Before invoking `sort` we first form an arrayref, with the whole string and its individual fields, so that the string need not be split later on every single comparison; this is [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)
- Criterion for the third-field: compare character by character alphabetically until a difference is found; if one string is contained in the other then the longer one wins. So the char-by-char comparison of `abc` and `ab` stops at `b` and `abc` 'wins'
- The (optional) fourth argument in [substr](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) is the replacement for the returned substring, found per the second and third argument. So here an empty string replaces one-long substring that starts at `0` -- it removes and returns the first character. This is quite like using `shift` on an array
- If the third fields are exactly the same then the second fields are compared numerically and if they are the same then the  first fields are compared alphabetically
- After the comparison we retrieve the original string from the sorted arrayrefs

Comment: Dare I say, this is beautiful. ;-) Thank you very much, @zdim And thank you very much for the in-depth explanation. Much appreciated.

Comment: @BillyJ Thank you very much for the kind words, I am very glad if it helped :)  I've added another comment.  Please let me know if questions pop up